# Counting the number of Vowels in Python

Tags: python

I have to count how many vowels (upper and lower) there are in a string. I must return an integer.

```
def count_vowels(sentence: str) -> int:
    lower = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    upper = ['A', 'E', 'I','O','U']
    vowels = 0
    for vowels in sentence:
        if vowels == lower or upper:
            vowels = vowels + 1
    return vowels
```

i am getting

vowels = vowels + 1
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

any tips?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What type is vowels? I’d start by studying strings in Python. Understand what it means to iterate over a string. Read, experiment, ask on QA forums. This site isn’t to teach people to code, it’s to answer specific technical questions. As such your question is likely to get closed as being off topic.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the same variable `vowels` for both counting and iterating over the character lists.

The count use expects an integer, the iteration use gets a string, hence your error.

It's best to have one purpose for a variable, and to give it a good name. For example `count` for counting, and `letter` for each letter in the sequence.

There is a second problem, this `if vowels == lower or upper` will not do what you think it does.

This code fixes both issues:

```py
def count_vowels(sentence: str) -> int:
    lower = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    upper = ['A', 'E', 'I','O','U']
    all_vowels = lower + upper
    count = 0
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter in all_vowels:
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Since you're learning, here is a slightly more advanced version. See if you can figure out how it works:

```py
def count_vowels2(sentence: str) -> int:
    lower = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    upper = ['A', 'E', 'I','O','U']
    all_vowels = lower + upper
    return sum(1 for letter in sentence if letter in all_vowels)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [str.count method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count)

```
def count_vowels(sentence: str) -> int:
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    sentence_lower = sentence.lower()

    return sum([sentence_lower.count(vowel) for vowel in vowels])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_sentence_1 = 'This is a sentence.'
    print(count_vowels(test_sentence_1))
```

Answer (score 3):

The error here is that vowels is first defined as an integer, 0 and then when you say "for vowels in sentence", now vowels are the character in the sentence

Below would be my implementation

```
def count_vowels(sentence: str) -> int:
    lower = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    upper = [x.upper() for x in lower]
    vowel_count = 0
    for letter in sentence:
        if (letter in lower) or (letter in upper):
            vowel_count += 1
    return vowel_count
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the explanation in the comments

```
def count_vowels(sentence: str) -> int:
lower = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
upper = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
vowels = 0  # here you implicitly say that vowels are int with initialized value of 0
for vowels in sentence:  # here you say that vowels are string
    if vowels == lower or upper:  # here you compare string with list (but you intend to check if the char is equal to one of the chars inside the list)
        vowels = vowels + 1  # here you try to add int to str which is not possible
return vowels
```

A correct approach would be to introduce a counter (I allowed myself to refactor the code according to clean code best practises):

```
def count_vowels(sentence: str) -> int:
lower_case_vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
upper_case_vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']

number_of_vowels = 0

for char in sentence:
    if char in lower_case_vowels or char in upper_case_vowels:
        number_of_vowels += 1

return number_of_vowels


print(count_vowels("This is a sentence."))
```

Answer (score 2):

So, here is the solution to your problem, plus the answer to the other problems in your code you didn't ask about - all explained as best as I can.

```
def count_vowels(sentence: str) -> int:
    lower = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    upper = ['A', 'E', 'I','O','U']
    vowels = 0
    for vowels in sentence:
        if vowels == lower or upper:
            vowels = vowels + 1
    return vowels
```

So there are a few problems, 1 of which is causing the error you are getting.

You first set `vowels` to `0`, correctly creating a integer variable to store the number of variables in.

However, you then proceed to say `for vowels in sentence`. The problem is that the variable `vowels` was already set, but now you are making a new variable called `vowels`, which is a string. When you say `for vowels in sentence`, you are saying 'the variable `vowel` will be the character we are up to while looping through the string called `sentence`' - so you are now overwriting the integer variable called `vowels` with a string variable called `vowels`.

So when you say `vowels = vowels + 1`, what are you doing? You are trying to add a string and a variable, which you can't do (that's just math - 10+Q=????????).

By being more specific when you set variable names, you can avoid the problem of using the same name for a variable twice. Like so:

```
def count_vowels(sentence: str) -> int:
    lower_cases = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    upper_cases = ['A', 'E', 'I','O','U']
    number_of_vowels = 0

    for letter in sentence:
        if letter == lower_cases or upper_cases:
            number_of_vowels += 1
    return number_of_vowels
```

So you see, we replace the variable representing the number of vowels in the sentence with `number_of_values` (you can never over-use underscores), and we make the variables in our for loop more accurate - `for letter in sentence`, as we are going through every letter in the sentence to see if its a vowel, we aren't just going through the vowels. We also change the name of the lists to `upper_cases` and `lower_cases` - again, to make them easier to remember and less likely to be confused.

However, we still have a problem - when you run this (try it!) you won't get the number of values, you'll get the number of letters in the sentence. That is because when checking if each letter is in the lists of upper and lower case letters, you are using the `==` operator instead of `in`. What's the difference?

The `==` operator is just meant for comparing 2 variables, while the `in` operator is for seeing if a string is inside a list. So if you are using `==`, number_of_vowels will be the total number of letters in the sentence.

Now its actually a strange fluke that using `==` gives you the number of letters in the sentence, because if you think about it, any letter won't be `==` to either `upper_cases` or `lower_cases`, because the letter is a string, and you are asking if its `==` to a list - and a string is a string and a list is a list, so they can't be `==`.

However, the key is the `or`. But first, a crash course in Boolean logic. Boolean logic is basically the idea that everything is either `True` (`1`) or `False` (`0`). If you go to your terminal and enter `2 == "a"`, it will return `False` - 2 is not the same as a. Same if you enter `"a" == ['a,']` - even they both contain the letter 'a', one is a string and one is a list - so they aren't `==`, hence the statement returning `False`.

So now, when you say `if letter == upper_cases`, we are saying 'if the statement `letter == upper_cases` returns `True` (because they are `==`), do what's on the next line. However, if it returns `False` (that they aren't `==`), don't do what is on the next line'.

So when you say `if letter == upper_cases` or `if letter == lower_cases` individually, you would get `False` - they are not `==`. But when you add an `or` in between, `if letter == upper_cases or lower_cases`, you get True. Why is that? `letter` isn't `==` to `upper_cases` or `lower_cases`!

The reason is, when comparing a string to 2 lists in Python, the second list will always be considered `Truthy` (just take my word for it, or check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)). So `letter == lower_cases` will return False, but `or upper` will be `Truthy`, hence the result of the statement `letter == upper_cases or lower_cases` to be `True` - because although the first half of the statement returns `False`, the second half is `Truthy`, which is the same as `True` for our purposes - so since one half of the statement is `True`, the result we get is `True`.

The solution is to use `in`, which checks if a string is in a list. So replace `if letter == upper_cases or lower_cases` with `if letter in lower or letter in upper`. If `letter` is in `upper_cases`, or if `letter` is in `lower_cases`, it will add 1 to `number_of_vowels`.

Congrats!

```
def count_vowels(sentence: str) -> int:
    lower = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    upper = ['A', 'E', 'I','O','U']
    number_of_vowels = 0

    for letter in sentence:
        if letter in lower or letter in upper:
            number_of_vowels += 1
            
    return number_of_vowels
```